# Make .btn-navbar show before site is resized at 940px or below in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basic question really. I love the .btn-navbar and it's responsiveness. By default, it will kick in at 940px or below. My question is how do I have just the .btn-navbar active at **all** times. All I want the user to see is the .btn-navbar to navigate. Here is the code I have now, though I suspect the .js file will need to be tweaked:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="#">Home</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **bootstrap-responsive.css** file, line 1078 you'll find:

```
  .navbar .btn-navbar {
    display: block;
  }
```

You can change this to:

```
.navbar {
        display: block;
      }
```

Then, add this in **bootstrap.css**:

```
.btn-navbar {
        display: block;
      }
```

That will get `.btn-navbar` to display in all screen widths.